# Removing multiple lines based on matches between two separate files

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a large file (.fastq 1.6Gb) where each entry is four lines where a new entry starts at the line that begins with @:

```
@SRR392137.1 I331_3_FC302WFAAXX:3:1:225:1941 length=35
GATGGTAGAAACATACGTCTT
+SRR392137.1 I331_3_FC302WFAAXX:3:1:225:1941 length=35
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
@SRR392137.2 I331_3_FC302WFAAXX:3:1:163:1931 length=35
GAATCATTTTGATAATAATAAGTTC
+SRR392137.2 I331_3_FC302WFAAXX:3:1:163:1931 length=35
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
@SRR392137.4 I331_3_FC302WFAAXX:3:1:164:1938 length=35
GACGGGTGAGTAACGCGTAAGAAC
+SRR392137.4 I331_3_FC302WFAAXX:3:1:164:1938 length=35
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
@SRR392137.5 I331_3_FC302WFAAXX:3:1:233:1936 length=35
GATGGTTTTGTCTGCTTAGATC
+SRR392137.5 I331_3_FC302WFAAXX:3:1:233:1936 length=35
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
```

I have a second file with a list of IDs (500,000 in total) that need to be removed from the .fastq file:

```
@SRR392137.2
@SRR392137.4
```

This would include removing the line containing the string and the next 3 lines underneath so that the output file would contain:

```
@SRR392137.1 I331_3_FC302WFAAXX:3:1:225:1941 length=35
GATGGTAGAAACATACGTCTT
+SRR392137.1 I331_3_FC302WFAAXX:3:1:225:1941 length=35
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
@SRR392137.5 I331_3_FC302WFAAXX:3:1:233:1936 length=35
GATGGTTTTGTCTGCTTAGATC
+SRR392137.5 I331_3_FC302WFAAXX:3:1:233:1936 length=35
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII
```

Is there anyway to do this using grep, sed or awk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For memory issue and using unhopefully a pipe

```
grep -v -f ListToExclude.file file.fastq \
 | sed -u -e '/^@/!d' -e 'N;N;N'
```

- The grep remove *entry* line from your list to remove
- The sed remove line that start not with `@`. If start with `@`, it also include the next 3 lines to output

  - the `-u` use the unbuffered option, usefull in this case

Answer (score 0):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  RS = "@"
}
NR == FNR {
  z[$1]
  next
}
$1 in z {
  next
}
{
  printf RS $0
}
```

Run like this:

```
alpha.awk list.ids large.fastq
```

Or

```
awk 'NR==FNR {z[$1];next} $1 in z {next} {printf RS$0}' RS=@ list.ids large.fastq
```

Comment: Thanks the above code worked great for my small files, but when I run it on the larger files I get the following error:

Comment: I have an error in the larger files which always stop at the same entry.  I presume its becuase it contains a @.  Is there a way to modify the code to take these into account                       @SRR392137.1854 I331_3_FC302WFAAXX:3:1:451:470 length=35
GAGAGAATATAGGATGGGTACCAT
+SRR392137.1854 I331_3_FC302WFAAXX:3:1:451:470 length=35
IIIIIIIIIIIIII@II&I:%$$+

Comment: @catcha I do not move with goalposts